# How to print each word returned from shell expansion on a separate line?

Tags: bash, shell

When we use shell expansion, it gives all the expanded word in one line. For example:

```
#!/bin/bash 
data="Hello\ {World,Rafi}"
eval echo $data
```

This produces the following output:

```
Hello World Hello Rafi
```

Is it possible to output each line on a separate line like this?

```
Hello World 
Hello Rafi
```

Comment: You're not using bash properly here. `eval` is evil, especially when you're not aware of its evilness! For example, if `data='Hello;ls'`, try `eval echo "$data"` you'll have a surprise. Now think of the case where `ls` is replaced by an evil command, e.g., `rm -rf .`... you definitely should rethink your strategy!

Comment: Thank you very much. I never thought in that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
data="Hello\ {World'\n',Rafi'\n',Kamal'\n'}"
eval echo -e "$data"
```

**echo -e** will evaluate newline characters.

Comment: Thanks it works :) But it also prints an extra newline in the start of the line, and if I move the newline at the end (`"Hello\ {World,Rafi}'\n'" an extra space is added from the second line and on.. is there any workaround?

Comment: @Rafi i've edited the answer. added new line char to end of every word. skip adding that if you dont want it.

Answer (score 5):

If I understand you right, you want to generate multiple words using brace expansion (`{...}`), then print each word on a separate line.

If you don't absolutely have to store `"Hello\ {World,Rafi}"` in a variable, you can do this with `printf` shell-builtin

```
printf "%s\n" "Hello "{Rafi,World}
```

---

### Some explanation:

The format string (here: `%s\n`) is reused until all the arguments to `printf` is used up ([Reference](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html)).

1. `%s\n` consumes 1 argument
2. `"Hello "{Rafi,World}` returns 2 words/arguments i.e. `"Hello Rafi"` and `"Hello World"`
3. So, this `printf` command is equivalent to

   ```
    printf "%s\n%s\n" "Hello Rafi" "Hello World"
   ```

   except you don't have to type *all* that up.

Comment: `+1` for _not_ mentioning `eval`.

Answer (score 3):

Same as Antarus'a answer, except that echo has "-n". From http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?echo

> -n     do not output the trailing newline

```
#!/bin/bash
data="Hello\ {World,Rafi}'\n'"
eval echo -n -e "$data"
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, your problem is not the expansion but the `echo` command. Depending on your system, you might get what you want by

```
#!/bin/bash
data="Hello\ {World\\\\n,Rafi}"
eval echo -e "$data"
```

Answer (score 1):

It is different solution but a very clean one.

```
#!/bin/bash

names="World Rafi"
for name in $names
do
    echo Hello $name
done
```

Comment: Or even `for name in {World,Rafi}; do ...`

Comment: `+1` for _not_ mentioning `eval`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `eval` (which is dangerous and really not a good practice — see my comment in your post), another strategy would be to use an array. The following will do exactly what you want, in a clean and safe way:

```
data=( "Hello "{World,Rafi} )
printf "%s\n" "${data[@]}"
```